# Safe to use binoculars in Dubai?

Tags: dubai

According to https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/united-arab-emirates/local-laws-and-customs , "Equipment like ... binoculars, may require a licence for use in the UAE."

Could I get in trouble for using consumer binoculars on the observation deck of Burj Khalifa or at other tourist sites around the city?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically to be on the safe side, ask at each place you intend to use them.

As the site you pointed out says, they may require a permit to use.

[WorldNomads](http://safety.worldnomads.com/United-Arab-Emirates/73798/What-You-Can-Or-Cant-Do-In-The-United-Arab-Emirates#axzz2qvxRzhl4) also cites it as a concern:

> Any form of hobby that involves cameras, binoculars or telescopes may
>   well be misunderstood by military or police officials if practiced
>   anywhere near a government building, military site or airport. Of
>   course, by misunderstood I mean they may arrest you, confiscate your
>   equipment and wonder what it was you found so interesting about their
>   military base. So, leave the bird watching or plane spotting for
>   places where you’re less liable to look like you’re up to something
>   dodgy basically.

And the site [crazy-travel](http://www.crazy-travel.com/infodubai.html) says almost exactly the same thing:

> Hobbies that involve cameras and binoculars, such as bird watching and
>   plane spotting, may be misunderstood - particularly near military
>   sites, government buildings and airports.

Long story short - it's better to ask at your hotel, and at the ticket office or information center for every place you intend to use them.

If you're concerned, there are the built-in binoculars at the top, [although they cost US$3 to use - for 2.5 minutes](http://www.rambleandwander.com/2012/09/uae-at-top-of-burj-khalifa.html).

Comment: If there are built-in binoculars at the top, it would be rather inconsistent to arrest people with personal binoculars for spying.

Comment: One would hope so!

Comment: There are many Digital binoculars available at the top with night vision and real time vision. you will be amazed.

Comment: @gerrit unless they were paid by the built-in binocular company

Answer (score 1):

I have been living in Dubai for last 7 years (I am an Indian national) and I have never had any issues with using binoculars. You will not have any issues with using binoculars in Dubai. Refrain from directly using it on people specially women and everything will be fine.

I have usually used it in sports events.